# javascript for loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have some experience in coding but I'm a total newbie in Javascript.

I try to create a html file which shows a google map and put some markers on it.

It works fine when I do it one marker at a time, like this:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = ...;
    var icon = ...;

    var pt1 = {lat: ..., lng: ...};
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt1,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        label: {..., text: '1'},
        title: 'Marker 1'
    });

    var pt2 = {lat: ..., lng: ...};
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt2,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        label: {..., text: '2'},
        title: 'Marker 2'
    });

    var pt3 = {lat: ..., lng: ...};
    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt3,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        label: {..., text: '3'},
        title: 'Marker 3'
    });
}
```

Now I tried to put the definition of the markers in an array and the creation of the markers in a loop, but I can't get it to work.

I tried it like this:

```
var places = [
    {id: 1, lat: ..., lng: ..., title: 'Marker 1'},
    {id: 2, lat: ..., lng: ..., title: 'Marker 2'},
    {id: 3, lat: ..., lng: ..., title: 'Marker 3'}
]

function initMap() {
    var map = ...;
    var icon = ...;

    for(var i=0; i<places.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: places[i].lat, lng: places[i].lng},
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            label: {..., text: ''+places[i].id},
            title: places[i].title
        });
    }
}
```

Putting an `window.alert(places[i].title)` inside the loop shows me all titles, so the definition of the array and the head of the loop seem to be ok. But as soon as I try to create the markers inside the loop no map and no markers are shown, so I guess there must be some kind of error, but I can't figure it out.

Do you see any syntactical errors I did?

Comment: any kind of error in console, are you sure your places[i].lat return a number and not a string instead?

Comment: Thank you, the mentioning of the console was the right tip. So much to learn about debugging javascript. I got several errors, all of them happened because I only used Notepad++ as an development environment (no code checks).
Is there any free development environment for javascript with intellisense and code checks, like Visual Studio for .NET?

Comment: VS Code (free) or Web Storm (paid).

Comment: If you are a student, you can have a free license with intelliJ idea, really good ide for web, otherwise there are atom, eclipse ...

P.s. get used to check/have always open the browser console error, it helps you a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the "marker" variable every time.

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

You will have to create an array for markers like you did for points (lat, long, tile).

It should be:

```
var places = [
    {id: 1, lat: ..., lng: ..., title: 'Marker 1'},
    {id: 2, lat: ..., lng: ..., title: 'Marker 2'},
    {id: 3, lat: ..., lng: ..., title: 'Marker 3'}
]

function initMap() {
    var map = ...;
    var icon = ...;
    var markers = [];

    for(var i=0; i<places.length; i++) {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: places[i].lat, lng: places[i].lng},
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            label: {..., text: ''+places[i].id},
            title: places[i].title
        }));
    }
}
```

And you should use const for the arrays (markers and places) and let in the for loop.

Comment: I knew that I override the marker variable in my loop, but since I don't do anything with this variable besides creating it, I didn't bother for now to put them in an array. But now I know how to do that, thank you.